Dua accepted while raining
I started praying and at the first I made four sunath and I made dua it was raining and when I started praying four farz the rain stop does it mean my dua is accepted

It does not necessarily mean anything as It could just be a coincidence.

Does it mean my dua accepted

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Assalam alaiko wa rahamtullah wa barakatu brother,
"Yes, it could be a sign of Allah accepting your dua but there are no evidence of this .
The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said,

'The supplication of a servant is answered as long as he does not show impatience or says, ‘I prayed but did not receive an answer.’’" (Sahih Muslim).

The change in the rain may be a sign of Allah's mercy and response to your prayer

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. to learn more about our site and the StackExchaneg model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].
